# How can I have a dropdown menu that changes to a burger icon when the screen is reduced and also includes my nav items inside it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm working in a part of my header which consists of a navbar that has 3 links in it and a dropdown menu that lists some additional links to other functionalities. This is the code I have right now:

```
<div class="col-md-4 pt-4">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container-fluid me-0 pe-0" style="width: fit-content">
        <a href="/index.php?action=who_are_we" class="black_links pe-2"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['who_are_we']; ?></a>
        <a href="/index.php?action=list_activities" class="black_links ps-2 pe-2"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['schedule']; ?></a>
        <a href="/index.php?action=contact" class="black_links ps-2 pe-2"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['contact']; ?></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['show_more']; ?>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end ">
                        <a href="/index.php?action=calendar"><li class="dropdown-item nav-link black_links"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['calendar']; ?></li></a>
                        <a href="/index.php?action=list_news"><li class="dropdown-item nav-link black_links"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['news']; ?></li></a>
                        <a href="/index.php?action=register"><li class="dropdown-item nav-link black_links"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['subscribe']; ?></li></a>
                        <a href="/index.php?action=login"><li class="dropdown-item nav-link black_links"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['login']; ?></li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My problem has to do with responsiveness. I'm using bootstrap to create this and what I have achieved is something like this in a large screen:
[Navbar in large screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T3hr.png)

But when I reduce the size of the screen to medium or less it doesn't work well. What I get is a burger-icon which is okay but inside of it there is only one item which is "Show more" and once I click on it, then it shows the rest of the items but in a weird way like this:
[Navbar in medium or less screen after clicking burger-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM96T.png)

And once I click on show more I get this:
[Navbar in medium or less screen after clicking on show more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQq4H.png)

What I would like to achieve is that once the burger-icon is displayed in a medium or smaller screen, when I click it I get the dropdown items and not the show more.

Also I would like to know how can I put the 3 items I have outside the dropdown in the navbar (who we are, schedule and contact) inside of the burger-icon once the screen shrinks. I'm not sure how this part can be made.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The style of the css code can be improved, right now the hamburger menu contains all the items and to remove the dropdown I used exclusively css:

```css
@media (max-width:991px){
        button.show-more {display: none;}
        ul.dropdown-menu {display: block;}
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
    </head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <a href="/index.php?action=who_are_we" class="black_links pe-2">Who are we <?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['who_are_we']; ?></a>
        <a href="/index.php?action=list_activities" class="black_links ps-2 pe-2">Schedule<?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['schedule']; ?></a>
        <a href="/index.php?action=contact" class="black_links ps-2 pe-2">Contact<?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['contact']; ?></a>

        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle show-more" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Show More
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['calendar']; ?>Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['news']; ?>News</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['subscribe']; ?>Subscribe</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?php echo $GLOBALS['translation']['login']; ?>Login</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```